# Физика в canvas. Программа плохо понимает столкновения объектов

Tags: javascript, canvas, физика

Согласно рекомендациям **@Stranger in the Q**, я сделал проверку на столкновения отдельным таймером, но так еще хуже. Может есть еще способы получше проверять столкновения?

Проверка во время отрисовки:

```js
function dotInObj(dotX, dotY, objX, objY, objWidth, objHeight) {
  if ((dotX >= objX && dotY >= objY) && (dotX <= objX + objWidth && dotY <= objY + objHeight)) return true;
  else return false;
} //функция проверки "точка в объекте"

function MacroCollision(obj1, obj2) {
  var XColl = false;
  var YColl = false;

  if ((obj1.X + obj1.width >= obj2.X) && (obj1.X <= obj2.X + obj2.width)) XColl = true;
  if ((obj1.Y + obj1.height >= obj2.Y) && (obj1.Y <= obj2.Y + obj2.height)) YColl = true;

  if (XColl & YColl) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

var cvs = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");
var touch = 0;

var objects = [];

var wall = {
  X: 0,
  Y: 0,
  mass: Infinity,
  width: 5,
  height: cvs.height,
  velocity: 0
}

function createObj(mass, velocity, position) { //функция создания объекта, position[0-1]
  objects.push({
    X: cvs.width * position - 30,
    Y: cvs.height - 30,
    mass: mass,
    width: 30,
    height: 30,
    velocity: velocity
  });
}

createObj(1000, -100, 1);
createObj(1, 0, 0.5); //созаю объекты

ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
let prevTime = 0;

function draw(t) { //функция отрисовки
  let dt = (t - prevTime) / 1000;
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cvs.width, cvs.height); //очистка после предыдущего кадра
  ctx.fillRect(wall.X, wall.Y, wall.width, wall.height); //стена
  for (let i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) { //отрисовка объектов
    ctx.fillRect(objects[i].X, objects[i].Y, objects[i].width, objects[i].height); //заполнение объекта(ов)
    objects[i].X += objects[i].velocity * dt; //передвижение объекта(ов) согласно его(их) скорости
  }
  let j = 1;
  for (let i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
    if (MacroCollision(objects[i], wall)) { //проверка на стык со стеной
      objects[i].velocity = Math.abs(objects[i].velocity) * Math.sign(-objects[i].velocity);
      touch++;
    }
    if (MacroCollision(objects[i], objects[j])) { //проверка столкновения 2 объектов

      if (j == i) continue; //от бага
      let x1 = objects[j].X + objects[j].width;
      let x2 = objects[i].X;
      let dx = x1 - x2;
      if (dx > 0)
        dx *= -1;
      objects[j].X += dx;
      let tx1 = objects[i].velocity;
      let tx2 = objects[j].velocity;
      let m2 = objects[i].mass + objects[j].mass;
      objects[i].velocity = ((objects[i].mass - objects[j].mass) * tx1 + 2.0 *
        objects[j].mass * tx2) / m2;
      objects[j].velocity = (2.0 * objects[i].mass * tx1 +
        (objects[j].mass - objects[i].mass) * tx2) / m2;
      touch++;
    }
  }
  ctx.font = "16px Arial";
  ctx.fillText(touch, 10, 20);
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  prevTime = t;
}

/* var timer = setInterval(function() {
  
}, 1);
 */
requestAnimationFrame(draw);
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<div class="canvasBG"></div>
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="250"></canvas>
<input type="text" id="console">
```

Проверка отдельным таймером:

```js
function dotInObj(dotX, dotY, objX, objY, objWidth, objHeight) {
  if ((dotX >= objX && dotY >= objY) && (dotX <= objX + objWidth && dotY <= objY + objHeight)) return true;
  else return false;
} //функция проверки "точка в объекте"

function MacroCollision(obj1, obj2) {
  var XColl = false;
  var YColl = false;

  if ((obj1.X + obj1.width >= obj2.X) && (obj1.X <= obj2.X + obj2.width)) XColl = true;
  if ((obj1.Y + obj1.height >= obj2.Y) && (obj1.Y <= obj2.Y + obj2.height)) YColl = true;

  if (XColl & YColl) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

var cvs = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");
var touch = 0;

var objects = [];

var wall = {
  X: 0,
  Y: 0,
  mass: Infinity,
  width: 5,
  height: cvs.height,
  velocity: 0
}

function createObj(mass, velocity, position) { //функция создания объекта, position[0-1]
  objects.push({
    X: cvs.width * position - 30,
    Y: cvs.height - 30,
    mass: mass,
    width: 30,
    height: 30,
    velocity: velocity
  });
}

createObj(1000, -100, 1);
createObj(1, 0, 0.5); //созаю объекты

ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
let prevTime = 0;

function draw(t) { //функция отрисовки
  let dt = (t - prevTime) / 1000;
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cvs.width, cvs.height); //очистка после предыдущего кадра
  ctx.fillRect(wall.X, wall.Y, wall.width, wall.height); //стена
  for (let i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) { //отрисовка объектов
    ctx.fillRect(objects[i].X, objects[i].Y, objects[i].width, objects[i].height); //заполнение объекта(ов)
    objects[i].X += objects[i].velocity * dt; //передвижение объекта(ов) согласно его(их) скорости
  }
  ctx.font = "16px Arial";
  ctx.fillText(touch, 10, 20);
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  prevTime = t;
}

var timer = setInterval(function() {
  let j = 1;
  for (let i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
    if (MacroCollision(objects[i], wall)) { //проверка на стык со стеной
      objects[i].velocity = Math.abs(objects[i].velocity) * Math.sign(-objects[i].velocity);
      touch++;
    }
    if (MacroCollision(objects[i], objects[j])) { //проверка столкновения 2 объектов

      if (j == i) continue; //от бага
      let x1 = objects[j].X + objects[j].width;
      let x2 = objects[i].X;
      let dx = x1 - x2;
      if (dx > 0)
        dx *= -1;
      objects[j].X += dx;
      let tx1 = objects[i].velocity;
      let tx2 = objects[j].velocity;
      let m2 = objects[i].mass + objects[j].mass;
      objects[i].velocity = ((objects[i].mass - objects[j].mass) * tx1 + 2.0 *
        objects[j].mass * tx2) / m2;
      objects[j].velocity = (2.0 * objects[i].mass * tx1 +
        (objects[j].mass - objects[i].mass) * tx2) / m2;
      touch++;
    }
  }
}, 1);

requestAnimationFrame(draw);
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<div class="canvasBG"></div>
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="250"></canvas>
<input type="text" id="console">
```

Проверка через сетинтервал:

```js
function dotInObj(dotX, dotY, objX, objY, objWidth, objHeight) {
  if ((dotX >= objX && dotY >= objY) && (dotX <= objX + objWidth && dotY <= objY + objHeight)) return true;
  else return false;
} //функция проверки "точка в объекте"

function MacroCollision(obj1, obj2) {
  var XColl = false;
  var YColl = false;

  if ((obj1.X + obj1.width >= obj2.X) && (obj1.X <= obj2.X + obj2.width)) XColl = true;
  if ((obj1.Y + obj1.height >= obj2.Y) && (obj1.Y <= obj2.Y + obj2.height)) YColl = true;

  if (XColl & YColl) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

var cvs = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");
var touch = 0;

var objects = [];

var wall = {
  X: 0,
  Y: 0,
  mass: Infinity,
  width: 5,
  height: cvs.height,
  velocity: 0
}

function createObj(mass, velocity, position) { //функция создания объекта, position[0-1]
  objects.push({
    X: cvs.width * position - 30,
    Y: cvs.height - 30,
    mass: mass,
    width: 30,
    height: 30,
    velocity: velocity
  });
}

createObj(1000, -100, 1);
createObj(1, 0, 0.5); //созаю объекты

ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
let prevTime = 0;

function draw(t) { //функция отрисовки
  let dt = (t - prevTime) / 1000;
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cvs.width, cvs.height); //очистка после предыдущего кадра
  ctx.fillRect(wall.X, wall.Y, wall.width, wall.height); //стена
  for (let i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) { //отрисовка объектов
    ctx.fillRect(objects[i].X, objects[i].Y, objects[i].width, objects[i].height); //заполнение объекта(ов)
    objects[i].X += objects[i].velocity * dt; //передвижение объекта(ов) согласно его(их) скорости
  }
  ctx.font = "16px Arial";
  ctx.fillText(touch, 10, 20);
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  prevTime = t;
}

var timer = setInterval(function() {
  let j = 1;
  for (let i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
    if (MacroCollision(objects[i], wall)) { //проверка на стык со стеной
      objects[i].velocity = Math.abs(objects[i].velocity) * Math.sign(-objects[i].velocity);
      touch++;
    }
    if (MacroCollision(objects[i], objects[j])) { //проверка столкновения 2 объектов

      if (j == i) continue; //от бага
      let x1 = objects[j].X + objects[j].width;
      let x2 = objects[i].X;
      let dx = x1 - x2;
      if (dx > 0)
        dx *= -1;
      objects[j].X += dx;
      let tx1 = objects[i].velocity;
      let tx2 = objects[j].velocity;
      let m2 = objects[i].mass + objects[j].mass;
      objects[i].velocity = ((objects[i].mass - objects[j].mass) * tx1 + 2.0 *
        objects[j].mass * tx2) / m2;
      objects[j].velocity = (2.0 * objects[i].mass * tx1 +
        (objects[j].mass - objects[i].mass) * tx2) / m2;
      touch++;
    }
  }
}, 1);

requestAnimationFrame(draw);
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<div class="canvasBG"></div>
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="250"></canvas>
<input type="text" id="console">
```

Comment: Не очень понятно, об чем вопрос. Что такое хорошо, спросила кроха? 

Так что единственное, что могу сказать - если делаешь проверку столкновений отдельным таймером, то и движение объектов нужно переместить в этот таймер (objects[i].X += objects[i].velocity * dt;) . В отрисовке - только отрисовка.

Comment: поддерживаю предыдущего оратора

Comment: В случае движения небольшого количества объектов с предсказуемой траекторией **не нужно вообще проверять столкновение** - вместо этого следует **предварительно рассчитать** момент столкновения. Для улучшения восприятия стоит сделать кадр точно в момент отскока и вставить его в последовательность кадров (старый хинт от аниматоров Диснея)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Видео про это задачу](http://%20youtube.com/watch?v=HEfHFsfGXjs)

Вот реализация которая считает правильно в плоть до пары `1e1` `1e15`.

Тут фокус в том, чтобы сильно уменьшить шаг между проверками коллизий, когда тяжелый блок прижал легкий к стене.

```js
console.log(Math.PI*1e7);
setTimeout(e => test(1), 100);

function test(mass) {
  var cvs = document.createElement('canvas');
  cvs.width = 300;
  cvs.height = 35;
  document.body.append(cvs);

  var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");
  var touch = 0;

  var wall, o1, o2, objects = [
      wall = {X: 0, Y: 0, width: 5, height: cvs.height, mass: Infinity, velocity: 0},
      o1 = {X: 100, Y: cvs.height - 20, width: 20, height: 20, mass: 1, velocity: 0},
      o2 = {X: 200, Y: cvs.height - 30, width: 30, height: 30, mass: mass, velocity: -250}
  ];

  let i, prevTime = Date.now(), goal = Math.floor(Math.PI*Math.sqrt(o2.mass));

  function draw() { 
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cvs.width, cvs.height);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'black'
    objects.forEach(o => ctx.fillRect(o.X, o.Y, o.width, o.height)); 
    ctx.fillStyle = touch === goal ? 'green' : 'red'
    ctx.fillText(touch, 10, 10);
    if (o2.X > cvs.width && o1.velocity >= 0 && o1.X > 20) {
      clearInterval(i);
    if (mass<1e14)
      test(mass*100)
    } else {
      requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    }
  }

  i = setInterval(e => {
    tick((Date.now() - prevTime) / 1000);
    while (o2.X < wall.width + o1.width) tick(o2.mass>1e5 ? 0.00001 : 0.001)
    prevTime = Date.now();
  });

  function tick(dt) {

      objects.forEach(o => o.X += o.velocity * dt);

      if (wall.X + wall.width > o1.X) { 
          o1.velocity = Math.abs(o1.velocity);
          touch++;
      }  

      if (o1.X + o1.width > o2.X) { 
          let dx = o1.X + o1.width - o2.X;
          if (dx > 0)
              dx *= -1;
          o1.X += dx;
          let tx1 = o2.velocity;
          let tx2 = o1.velocity;
          let m1 = o2.mass - o1.mass;
          let m2 = o2.mass + o1.mass;
          o2.velocity = (m1 * tx1 + 2 * o1.mass * tx2) / m2;
          o1.velocity = (2 * o2.mass * tx1 - m1 * tx2) / m2;
          touch++;
      }

      o1.X = Math.max(5, o1.X);  
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
```

```css
body{margin:0}canvas{background-color:#eee;}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вот наш с другом вариант
https://jsfiddle.net/sazdan/mcL72ft5/16/, ну и Ваш, который выполняется вручную: https://jsfiddle.net/sazdan/mcL72ft5/27/


Вот только как и в Вашем, так и в нашем, остается проблема лишнего нуля (т.е. при массе 10000, должно написать 4 цифры числа пи - 3141 при 100000 - 5 и т.д.) и проблема "через раз", то есть: при массе 1: пишет 3, масса 10: 10(ошибка), масса 100: 31, масса 1000: 117(ошибка), масса 10000: 314 (полуошибка, должно быть 3141), масса 100000: 993 (ошибка), масса 1000000: 3141 (полуошибка, должно быть 31415) и т.д.

Comment: @ДаниилСазонов вроде сейчас правильно считает

Answer (score 1):

Вот версия, которая работает более менее стабильно, однако ответ не верный...

Так же я изменил секцию где определяется направление движения после столкновения со стеной, она не может быть влево, по этому я убрал второй множитель

```js
function MacroCollision(obj1, obj2) {
  return obj1.X + obj1.width >= obj2.X && obj1.X <= obj2.X + obj2.width;
}

var cvs = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");
var touch = 0;
var objects = [];

var wall = {
  X: -1000,
  Y: 0,
  mass: Infinity,
  width: 1005,
  height: cvs.height,
  velocity: 0
}

function createObj(mass, velocity, position) { //функция создания объекта, position[0-1]
  objects.push({
    X: cvs.width * position - 30,
    Y: cvs.height - 30,
    mass: mass,
    width: 30,
    height: 30,
    velocity: velocity
  });
}

createObj(10000, -50, 1);
createObj(1, 0, 0.5); //созаю объекты

ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
let prevTime = Date.now();

function draw(t) { //функция отрисовки
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cvs.width, cvs.height); //очистка после предыдущего кадра
  ctx.fillRect(wall.X, wall.Y, wall.width, wall.height); //стена
  for (let i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) { //отрисовка объектов
    ctx.fillRect(objects[i].X, objects[i].Y, objects[i].width, objects[i].height); //заполнение 
  }
  ctx.font = "16px Arial";
  ctx.fillText(touch, 10, 20);
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

var timer = setInterval(function() {
  let dt = (Date.now() - prevTime) / 1000;
  prevTime = Date.now();
  let j = 1;
  for (let i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {

    objects[i].X += objects[i].velocity * dt; //передвижение объекта(ов) согласно его(их) скорости
    
    objects[i].X = Math.max(5, objects[i].X)
  
    if (MacroCollision(objects[i], wall)) { //проверка на стык со стеной
      objects[i].velocity = Math.abs(objects[i].velocity);
      touch++;
    }
    
    if (MacroCollision(objects[i], objects[j])) { //проверка столкновения 2 объектов
      if (j == i) continue; //от бага
      let x1 = objects[j].X + objects[j].width;
      let x2 = objects[i].X;
      let dx = x1 - x2;
      if (dx > 0)
        dx *= -1;
      objects[j].X += dx;
      let tx1 = objects[i].velocity;
      let tx2 = objects[j].velocity;
      let m2 = objects[i].mass + objects[j].mass;
      objects[i].velocity = ((objects[i].mass - objects[j].mass) * tx1 + 2.0 *
        objects[j].mass * tx2) / m2;
      objects[j].velocity = (2.0 * objects[i].mass * tx1 +
        (objects[j].mass - objects[i].mass) * tx2) / m2;
      touch++;
    }
  }
});

requestAnimationFrame(draw);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="150" style="border: 1px solid #999"></canvas>
```

Comment: Полагаю, Вы тоже смотрели то видео про элегантное вычисление числа Пи :)
То есть, ошибка в формулировке физических законов?

Comment: @ДаниилСазонов да, это с канала 3 blue 1 brown https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HEfHFsfGXjs

Comment: @ДаниилСазонов а вот теперь правильный ответ, однако это все равно не честная реализация, догадаетесь где ошибка? :)

Comment: Запрет на продвижение тяжелого объекта дальше 5 координаты по Х.
Я как раз планировал в будущем реализовать что-то подобное)
Вот только из-за неправильной формулировки, таким образом ответ правильный только для 1 и 10000 масс.

Comment: @ДаниилСазонов 1 и 100 тоже дают 31, дальше надо править то что происходит в момент коллизии, я просто ограничил, как Вы верно отметили координату по Х, однако надо еще посчитать на сколько отскочил объект в этот момент.

Comment: @ДаниилСазонов https://codepen.io/strangerintheq/pen/YoeQbY?editors=0010 вот тут ответы правильные а визуазизация нет, дождался пары 1e1 1e9

Comment: Версия с графиком: https://jsfiddle.net/sazdan/mcL72ft5/80/